# Getting Multiple values from Single Td( Hidden field and label) values

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im working on a task where im geting list of data from data base and binding it to Html table.
Each row have Identity Column but that doesnt display on table which is hidden within Table Td.
If any new record is inserted if that have Id then it should update...If new record doesnt have any id then it should Insert into database usng jquery Ajax.

### here is the code

```
<table border="1" id="tbuser">


     <tr style="background-color:burlywood; color:black">


                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address1</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Edit</th>

            </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> <input type="hidden" id="Id" value="@item.ID" /><label id="Name">@item.Name</label></td>
                <td><label id="Phone">@item.Phone</label></td>
                <td><label id="Email">@item.Email</label></td>
                <td><label id="Address">@item.Address1</label></td>
                <td><label id="Country">@item.Country</label></td>
                <td><label id="State">@item.State</label></td>
                <td><label id="City">@item.City</label></td>


            </tr>                                                                               

        }

    </table>
```

here is the code for ajax implementation

```
$("#btnupdate").click(function () {

            var Details = [];

            debugger;
            var tabledetails = $("#tbuser").find("tr").each(function (index,obj) {
                var Id = $("#Id").val();
                var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
                debugger
                var details = {};



                details.Id = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
                details.Name = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
                details.Phone = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
                details.Email = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
                details.Address1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
                details.Country = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text();
                details.State = currentRow.find("td:eq(6)").text();
                details.City = currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text();





                if (index >= 1)
               {
                 Details.push(details);
                    //calling ajax
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/demo/Updatetabel',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(Details),
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Record Updated");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occured!!!");
                }
            });


        });
```

Comment: inside your foreach, your having multiple `id="Phone"` and so on, An ID should always be unique. Use class if you shall have multiple attributes with the same parameter.

Answer (score 0):

ID's should always be unique.

Second, then I changed a bit of your code and remove the ajax ( just for the example) I hope this solves your problems.

**demo**

```js
$("#btnupdate").click(function() {

  var Details = [];

  var tabledetails = $("#tbuser").find("tr").each(function(index, obj) {
    var currentRow = $(this);
    var Id = currentRow.find("td:eq(0) input").val();
    var details = {};
    details.Id = Id + currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    details.Name = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    details.Phone = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    details.Email = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
    details.Address1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text();
    details.Country = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text();
    details.State = currentRow.find("td:eq(6)").text();
    details.City = currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text();





    if (index >= 1) {
      Details.push(details);
      //calling ajax
    }
  });
console.log(Details)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tbuser">


  <tr style="background-color:burlywood; color:black">


    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Address1</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Edit</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="hidden" class="Id" value="1" /><label class="Name">1</label></td>
    <td><label class="Phone">1</label></td>
    <td><label class="Email">1</label></td>
    <td><label class="Address">1</label></td>
    <td><label class="Country">1</label></td>
    <td><label class="State">1</label></td>
    <td><label class="City">1</label></td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="hidden" class="Id" value="2" /><label class="Name">2</label></td>
    <td><label class="Phone">2</label></td>
    <td><label class="Email">2</label></td>
    <td><label class="Address">2</label></td>
    <td><label class="Country">2</label></td>
    <td><label class="State">2</label></td>
    <td><label class="City">2</label></td>


  </tr>

</table>

<button id="btnupdate">btnupdate</button>
```